# Asynchronous Threading that is not coming over correctly using a code converter from C# to VB

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, c#-to-vb.net

I have some C# code that is doing a asynchronous call and pulling back a data set. I do this so the windows desktop UI does not hang/freeze while it is being retrieved. I now need to do the same thing in vb.net but after putting in through an online code converter it gives me the error.

> Delegate 'Func(Of String, Boolean, DataSet)' requires an 'AddressOf' expression or lambda expression as the only argument to its constructor.

Here is the code before and after conversion.

Before:

```
var DataFunc = new Func<string, string, DataSet> (getData);

IAsyncResult Result = DataFunc.BeginInvoke(barCodeResult, orderType, null, null);

DataSet ds = DataFunc.EndInvoke(Result);
```

After:

```
Dim DataFunc As var = New Func(Of String, String, DataSet)(getData)

Dim Result As IAsyncResult = DataFunc.BeginInvoke(barCodeResult, orderType, Nothing, Nothing)

Dim ds As DataSet = mtrDataFunc.EndInvoke(Result)
```

Thank you very much in advance for your insights.

Comment: You should understand the language instead of using converters. Almost all .NET code is written in C#. The original C# code is *not* good. I suspect it was copied from a very old project. You can replace it with `var result=await Task.Run(()=>getData(barCodeResult,orderType));`. The equivalent in VB.NET is `Dim result=Await Task.Run(Function() getData(barCodeResult,orderType))`

Comment: What does `getData` do? There's no point in running anything in the background if the function blocks waiting for a database response. ADO.NET itself supports asynchronous operations. eg, `SqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync` can be used to return a reader asynchronously

Answer (score 1):

There are two fixes to be made:

1. There's no data type called `var`. In this case you can replace `As var =` with `As New`.
2. As the error states, the method that you pass to the `Func` constructor must be prepended by [**`AddressOf`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx) to create a delegate.

   ```
   Dim DataFunc As New Func(Of String, String, DataSet)(AddressOf getData)
   ```

Comment: Good answer, but the usual VB equivalent to inferred typing is to use 'Option Infer On' and then omit the type: Dim DataFunc = ...

Comment: The actual equivalent since 2012 would be `Dim result=Await Task.Run(Function() getData(barCodeResult,orderType))`.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas : I had that at first, but edited it within the 5 minutes before the edit history starts.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : The _actual_ equivalent is this, however the _better_ equivalent is your suggestion. :)

Comment: The original code is bad C#. In fact, if `getData` talks to a database, executing it in the background just wastes a thread.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I didn't say it is a good way of doing it, I just said it is the _actual_ conversion. I don't disagree with that he should use your method, and I think you should write it as an answer. -- Thanks for the heads-up on the issue though. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent: Yes - it's probably clearer anyway to use "Dim DataFunc As New ..." - i.e., the shortcut that VB's had all along to avoid typing out the type name twice.  Just thought I'd point out that it's not inferred typing like the original C#.